# What exactly is transfer rate?

Tags: assembly, x86, hardware

Text on a website states,

```
Each BUS CYCLE on the 8086 equals four system clocking periods (T states).
The clock rate is 5MHz , therefore one Bus Cycle is 800ns .
The transfer rate is 1.25MHz.
```

Now I get the first two points but I am unable to understand the term transfer rate. I understand how it is calculated but I am unable to understand the why is it called transfer rate. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can perform one transfer every `T` seconds then the there can be up to `1/T` transfers per second. For `t = 800 ns = 0.0000008 s` this gives `1,250,000 transfers per second = 1.25 MHz`.

Another way of looking at it is that the clock rate is `5 MHz` but if it takes 4 clocks to perform a transfer, then you will only get a transfer rate of one quarter of the clock rate, i.e. `5 MHz / 4 = 1.25 MHz`.